# How to skip missing images/frames within an image sequence when used with cv2.videocapture()?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have around 40K frames stored in a directory. I am using following code to read them and eventually write them in a video file. The following snippet is just for displaying the video.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/images/%010d.jpg')
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret == True):
        cv2.imshow('video output', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(30)
```

It works until there is a missing image in the sequence.For ex. in my case I do not have image '0000000021.jpg'. So it return the following error:

```
[image2 @ 0x1401500] Could not open file : path/to/images/0000000021.jpg
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I get the name of the missing image/frame?
2. Is there a way to tell the cap.read() function to just chill and increment the next sequence, for eg. in my case skip '0000000021.jpg' and go to '0000000022.jpg' and so on.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't produce the error, therefore my answer may not be accurate.

But it may give you a clue on how to solve it.

I think for both questions, the following is the answer:

```
from cv2 import VideoCapture
from cv2 import imshow, waitKey

missing_frames = []

capture = VideoCapture('path/to/images/%010d.jpg')

while True:
    _, frame = capture.read()

    if frame is None:
        missing_frames.append(frame)
    else:
        imshow('out', frame)
        waitKey(0)
```

**Explanation**

You are reading a sequence of images using `VideoCapture` and there are some missing frames in the directory.

If a frame is missing, `ret` returns False and `frame` returns `None`.

```
ret, frame = capture.read()
```

I understand you are focusing on reading and writing the frames. Therefore you don't need `ret` variable. Just checking `frame` is enough.

if `frame` is not available in the directory, add it to the `mssing_frames` list. Otherwise display it.

I try to give you an opinion of how you solve it. If you ask me, I solve the problem as below:

```
from os import getcwd
from os.path import join
from cv2 import imshow
from cv2 import waitKey
from cv2 import imread
from glob import glob


def get_integer(frame_name):
    frame_name = frame_name.replace(path, '')
    frame_name = frame_name.replace('.jpg', '')
    frame_number = int(frame_name[1:])
    return frame_number


if __name__ == '__main__':
    missing_frames = []
    path = join(getcwd(), 'test-case')
    capture = glob(join(path, '*.jpg'))

    name = capture[0]
    name_num = get_integer(name)

    for frame in capture:
        frame_num = get_integer(frame)

        if name_num != frame_num:
            missing_frames.append(frame)

        imshow('out', imread(frame))
        waitKey(0)
        name_num += 1

    print(missing_frames)
```

Output:

```
['/Users/ahmettavli/PycharmProjects/StackOverFlow/test-case/0000000023.jpg']
```

I stored all the images using `glob` and I check whether there is a missing frame by its number.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. In the 'finally' block I am now copying the missing frame from another directory, so in the next iteration **videocapture** object finds that frame: **cheap fix alert!!**. Do you have any suggestions for my second question? I want to tell the **videocapture** object to skip a missing frame. This might be the **ultimate** fix O)

Comment: So, the **capture.read()**  function should try to read the next frame once we handle a false **ret* right?. If yes, then this is not happening in my code. The **cap.read** tries to keep reading the missing frame indefinitely. And does not move to the next frame.I  have two frame directories,  **/all-frames/** & **/missing-frames/**. The cap.read() is reading from **/missing-frames-dir/** and when it encounters a missing frame I copy that frame from **/all-frames-dir/** (workaround) and only then the cap.read() moves to the next frame. It's like the cap.read() can not skip a missing frame.

Comment: the capture.read() function should try to read the next frame once we handle a false ret* right? No, not as simple as that. Please read my answer one more time , since I suggested the usage of `glob`. I tested the code and yes I find out the missing frame without error.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: In the first example, what's the point of `missing_frames.append(frame)`? -- You're just making a list of `None`s... If the frame is not available, then there's nothing to add.

Comment: @DanMašek The reason I have initialized the  `missing_frames` is that the OP asked for the names of the missing frames. Most probably the time I've answered the question I thought of using the list.