# OpenCV (Python) VideoCapture.read() on missing frames

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

New to python, new to OpenCV, which I'm gonna use for my master-thesis, and already got some problems using the VideoCapture object of OpenCV.

**Situation:**
I got 2 folders containing corresponding images (taken with RGB and infrared cameras). I want to display them sibe by side in a Window using a while-loop. The problem arises, when there are some images missing from one of the image-sequences (Due to problems while recording or whatever, I don't really know but that should be of no importance). My idea was to use the bool-returnvalue of the .read() function to check wheather there is a frame to be read and if not, replace the image by a black one. This is what I did:

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

pathRGB = "Bilder/RGB"
pathIR = "Bilder/IR"
# the paths to the folders containing the images

capRGB = cv2.VideoCapture(pathRGB + "/frame_%06d.jpg")
capIR = cv2.VideoCapture(pathIR + "/frame_%06d.jpg")
# setting up the VideoCapture-elements with the according format

shapeRGB = capRGB.read()[1].shape
shapeIR = capIR.read()[1].shape
# get the shape of the first image in each folder to later create the black
# dummy-image

dtypeRGB = capRGB.read()[1].dtype
dtypeIR = capIR.read()[1].dtype
# get the type of the first image in each folder to later create the black
# dummy-image

if (capRGB.isOpened() is False):
    print("Error opening RGB images")
if (capIR.isOpened() is False):
    print("Error opening IR images")

cv2.namedWindow("frames", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while capRGB.isOpened() and capIR.isOpened() is True:
    retRGB, imgRGB = capRGB.read()
    retIR, imgIR = capIR.read()
    # read both images

    if retRGB is True and retIR is False:
        imgIR = np.zeros(shapeIR, dtype=dtypeIR)
    # if there is no IR image, crate a dummy one
    if retIR is True and retRGB is False:
        imgRGB = np.zeros(shapeRGB, dtype=dtypeRGB)
    # if there is no RGB image, crate a dummy one
    if retRGB is False and retIR is False:
        break

    imgCombined = np.hstack((imgRGB, imgIR))
    # put both images together
    cv2.imshow("frames", imgCombined)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord("q"):
        break

capRGB.release()
capIR.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Problem:**
From my understanding, the problem arises as capIR.read() attempts to read a missing image (in my case the 527th) and instead of just returning false/None it attempts to read the same image over and over again. Up to the missing frame, everything works fine, the right "IR" image even turns black but then the videoplayback begins to slow down and while i still can close the window by pressing 'q', spyder IDE freezes and if I wait "too long" i even have to shut it down. Console gives out "[image2 @ 000002a7af8f0480] Could not open file : Bilder/IR/frame_000527.jpg" over and over again, so much that i can't scroll to the top.
I guess what I'm asking is: Is there any way to make the .read() function just attempt 1 read and after it fails continue with the next frame?

Best regards and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does VideoCapture work in case frame numbers are missing in case the frames are single JPEG files? The error message “could not open file …” Would let me assume it does not.

Comment: You could check for the largest frame numbers for your captures and iterate manually, skipping missing files and using cv2.read for reading the JPEG files. Or save dummy black image files for the missing frames in the corresponding directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip missing images/frames within an image sequence when used with cv2.videocapture()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247244/how-to-skip-missing-images-frames-within-an-image-sequence-when-used-with-cv2-vi)

Comment: you could file an issue and ask that the behavior be changed so CAP_IMAGES simply keeps incrementing regardless. I can imagine situations where retrying would be useful though, so this might result in some CAP_PROP flag to switch behavior. I think skipping should be default. -- quick workaround: write your own class that increments an internal counter and tries to read the images in sequence, skipping instead of retrying. or the same, without a class, but the code won't be substantially less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulated for testing with different files and directory names.

Will retrieve the largest frame number from both directories and afterwards iterate over all frame numbers for reading the files from both directories.

```
import os
import cv2
import re
import glob

image_dir1 = 'test1'
image_dir2 = 'test2'

# retrieve all frames in both directories
frames_cap1 = glob.glob(os.path.join(image_dir1, "frame_*.jpg"))
frames_cap2 = glob.glob(os.path.join(image_dir2, "frame_*.jpg"))

# sort inscending
frames_cap1.sort()
frames_cap2.sort()

# retrieve last frame No for both directories
last_frame_cap1 = frames_cap1[-1]
last_frame_cap2 = frames_cap2[-1]

# extract integer counter as a group
# modify regex to match file name if required 
match_cap1 = re.search('frame_(\d+).jpg', last_frame_cap1)
match_cap2 = re.search('frame_(\d+).jpg', last_frame_cap2)
last_frame_no_cap1 = int(match_cap1.group(1))
last_frame_no_cap2 = int(match_cap2.group(1))

# retrieve max frame No
max_frame_no = max(last_frame_no_cap1, last_frame_no_cap2)

for i in range(max_frame_no + 1):
    # adapt formatting of frame number to digit count in file name
    # here: 6 digits with leading zeros
    image_path_cap1 = os.path.join(image_dir1, f"frame_{i:06d}.jpg")
    image_path_cap2 = os.path.join(image_dir2, f"frame_{i:06d}.jpg")
    
    if not os.path.isfile(image_path_cap1):
        print(f"handle missing file: '{image_path_cap1}'")
        # ...
    else:
        img1 = cv2.imread(image_path_cap1)
        # …

    if not os.path.isfile(image_path_cap2):
        print(f"handle missing file: '{image_path_cap2}'")
        # ...
    else:
        img2 = cv2.imread(image_path_cap2)
        # …
# …
```

Comment: This is how I ended up implementing it, thank you very much. It seems that the videocapture thing was not really the tool i was looking for. I fiddled around with it some more and found that if i would delete a single image from a folder of an imageseries and than setting the current frame to the one after the missing one using the .set method and the CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES parameter, .read() still wouldn't work. Just after about 15 frames after the missing one, a new frame can be read successfully. I think it has to to with some videocodec-stuff, don't know, don't care anymore(I hope:D). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the images in directory1 have the same names as directory2 images, but we know that some image may not be present in both directories...

```
import glob,os,cv2

path1 = "folder1/"
path2 = "folder2/"

#change directory to path1 
os.chdir(path1)
l1 = glob.glob("*.jpg")   #get a list of images names 

os.chdir("../")  #go one directory up


blackimg = cv2.imread("blackimg.jpg")

for fname in l1:

    #check if image1 exists , then read it .  otherwise im1 = blackimg
    if os.path.isfile(path1+fname):
        im1=cv2.imread(path1+fname)
    else:
        im1=blackimg
    
    #check if image2 exists , then read it .  otherwise im2 = blackimg
    if os.path.isfile(path2+fname):
        im2=cv2.imread(path2+fname)
    else:
        im2=blackimg

    imgCombined = np.hstack((im1, im2))


    cv2.imshow("Combined", imgCombined)
    print("press any key to continue, q to exit")
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) 
    if k == ord("q"):break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The list `l1` will contain the source directory `path1` as well when using `glob` , therefore the parent directory has to be removed from `fname` to make it work for `l2` as well.